# How to stop mediaplayer while playing on background?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am developing a music player on android and the app has two activities (MainActivity and PlayActivity). In the MainActivity I have a listview with a list of songs and in the PlayActivity I have a button to listen and pause the music. The problem is that when go back to MainActivity and I select a new song from the listview, the first one keeps playing on background while the second one also starts playing. How can I stop the first song when I select a new one?
(I don't want to stop mediaplayer onBackPressed, I just want to stop the music when another song it's selected from listview and play a fresh song in PlayActivity)

EDIT: I'm using AsyncTask to start mediaplayer on PlayActivity: mp.prepareAsync();

Comment: What component owns the media player? Is it hosted in a `Service`?

Comment: I'm using: prepareAsync()

Comment: What `Context` is used to create the player?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to stop `MediaPlayer` when `onBackPressed()`

```
MediaPlayer  mp ; // mp is your MediaPlayer

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void playMusic() {
    if (mp != null) {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();

            MediaPlayer copyMp = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                copyMp.setDataSource("/path");
                mp = copyMp;
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer)

> MediaPlayer is not thread-safe. Creation of and all access to player
> instances should be on the same thread.

That means you have to maintain one media player instance throughout your whole application(As per your requirement). I don't know how you implemented the media player(Service/AsyncTask etc.). When you select a new song, you need to access that instance and replace the existing song with the selected one.